fix wrong spelling after a run of correct spellings in a sorted dataframe in pandas
I have a dataframe like this:
Bevonce,2008,296853
Beyonce,2007,1210744
Beyonce,2007,1222003
Beyonce,2007,1222003
Beyonce,2007,1222007
Beyoncel,2007,1222002
Nicki Mina,2015,2717068
Nicki Minaj,2015,2741567
Nicki Minaj,2015,2741567
Nicki Minaj,2015,2743565
Nicki Minajl,2015,2744974
Nicki Minal,2015,2741562
Nickl Minaj,2015,2741867

I want to clean it to:
Beyonce,2008,296853
Beyonce,2007,1210744
Beyonce,2007,1222003
Beyonce,2007,1222003
Beyonce,2007,1222007
Beyonce,2007,1222002
Nicki Minaj,2015,2717068
Nicki Minaj,2015,2741567
Nicki Minaj,2015,2741567
Nicki Minaj,2015,2743565
Nicki Minaj,2015,2744974
Nicki Minaj,2015,2741562
Nicki Minaj,2015,2741867

Note : the kind of erros are
   - single charecter wrong 
   - single charecter more  
   - single charecter less  
   - or combination of two of the above

And to avoid false positive I am thinking of cleaning a string only if I find its variation after a run of at least 3 rows of identical first columns(and hence expected to be correct) and that run of identical values can be used as source of truth for the following or preceding mismatching string.
As you can see in example Bevonce is the variation from the following 4 run of Beyonce and also Beyoncel is mismatching from 4 run of preceding Beyonce.
Also you can assume my dataframe is always expected to be in sorted order of first column.

Having the names sorted doesn't help if the misspelling is, for example, in the first letter - e.g., Geyoncé

Your proposed mechanism for establishing a source of truth is flawed. In your cod, for example, Nicki Mina will not be corrected, and if it occurred on the row below, n errors in Nicki Minaj would be corrected. There are similar flaws in Beyonce. I'd look at counting the variations of names, and taking the most frequent as the true spelling, then calculating the Levenshtein distance for other names and correcting everything with a distance less than, say, 2. Starting with a lookup list would be dramatically more accurate and faster. There may be better ways.

@TangentiallyPerpendicular We don't have the luxury of lookup list. It has to be dynamically computed. How do you know most frequent ?  Some run may be so long  that errornous frequency would me more than some valid run length. secondly in your frequency map how many of the bottom would you count as errornous. half ? ie assuming each valid has one erroous pair ?

@TangentiallyPerpendicular  In my mechanism    Nicki Mina follows single character less rule. creating the source of truth of by seeing the next 3 can be flowed if all the following 3 are wrong with exact same error. is that what you mean by flawed ? I dont see any other case of flaw

@SIGHUP yes it helps in some cases, it doesn't in some like the one you mentioned ie first character wrong. So what' do you suggest, let's listen to all ideas?

@ishandutta2007 You would need to devise or utilise some algorithm that determines if any two words can be deemed so similar as to be considered equal

@SIGHUP We can view it as a clustering problem, with each item starting in its own cluster. Now we merge two clusters when either their representative(ie the string name) is identical or one is 2 unit Levenshtein_distancy away from the other and also one cluster has to be at least 3x bigger than the other in size(ie in number of elements) when the merge is taking place for non-identical case. The bigger cluster's representative is chosen as the new cluster's representative. and we repeat the process untll no more merging is possible. Let me know what flaw you see in this approach . –

Does condition "combination of two of the above" include "combination of the same two of the above"? I mean, Beyonce and Beyon or Beyonce and Bevonse are the same?

@BogdanShevchenko Bevonse is wrong charter twice. Not two different of above rule . So I  didn't consider it. Having said tha,t don't focus on those rules so strictly, loosely speaking levenshtein_distance<=2 should be enough.

That was the main motivation of my question, to understand if levenshtein distance is good for this task (because L. distance between Bevonse and Beyonce = 2)

Using Levenshtein.distance to compute the number of differences (we'll use 2 differences as a threshold), networkx.connected_components to form the clusters of connected names, and statistics.mode to identify the most common name in each cluster:
from Levenshtein import distance
from itertools import combinations
import networkx as nx
from statistics import mode

names = df['name']

G = nx.Graph()

for i,j in combinations(df.index, 2):
    if distance(names[i], names[j]) <= 2:
        G.add_edge(i, j)

out = {}
for c in nx.connected_components(G):
    name = mode(names[i] for i in c)
    out.update(dict.fromkeys(c, name))

df['common_name'] = out

NB. this requires unique indices in the DataFrame's index.
Output:
            name  year    other  common_name
0        Bevonce  2008   296853      Beyonce
1        Beyonce  2007  1210744      Beyonce
2        Beyonce  2007  1222003      Beyonce
3        Beyonce  2007  1222003      Beyonce
4        Beyonce  2007  1222007      Beyonce
5       Beyoncel  2007  1222002      Beyonce
6     Nicki Mina  2015  2717068  Nicki Minaj
7    Nicki Minaj  2015  2741567  Nicki Minaj
8    Nicki Minaj  2015  2741567  Nicki Minaj
9    Nicki Minaj  2015  2743565  Nicki Minaj
10  Nicki Minajl  2015  2744974  Nicki Minaj
11   Nicki Minal  2015  2741562  Nicki Minaj
12   Nickl Minaj  2015  2741867  Nicki Minaj

Graph of nodes with distances:

If the groups are sorted
If you know that the input groups are sorted, you only need to compare the successive pairs. If a distance is above the threshold, consider it a new group:
from Levenshtein import distance
import numpy as np

group = np.cumsum([distance(a,b)>2 for a,b in
                   zip(df['name'], df['name'].shift(fill_value=''))])

df['common_name'] = df.groupby(group)['name'].transform(lambda x: x.mode()[0])

Output:
            name  year    other  common_name
0        Bevonce  2008   296853      Beyonce
1        Beyonce  2007  1210744      Beyonce
2        Beyonce  2007  1222003      Beyonce
3        Beyonce  2007  1222003      Beyonce
4        Beyonce  2007  1222007      Beyonce
5       Beyoncel  2007  1222002      Beyonce
6     Nicki Mina  2015  2717068  Nicki Minaj
7    Nicki Minaj  2015  2741567  Nicki Minaj
8    Nicki Minaj  2015  2741567  Nicki Minaj
9    Nicki Minaj  2015  2743565  Nicki Minaj
10  Nicki Minajl  2015  2744974  Nicki Minaj
11   Nicki Minal  2015  2741562  Nicki Minaj
12   Nickl Minaj  2015  2741867  Nicki Minaj


It works but this is brute force approach as you are computing Levenshtein distance between every pairs. it's O(n^2), too slow for my dataset. My initial idea of keeping the rows sorted and computing Levenshtein distance with only neighbours might have speedup things but it could have missed out some cases as @Sighup pointed out. I am  looking for best of both worlds ie which solves in O(n*log n) and misses out on minimal cases. Am not sure if the problem is perfectly solvable in O(n*log n). maybe I should create a question on cs.stackexchange if I don't receive more efficient solution.

@ishandutta2007 sorting won't really help, in the end you have to compare all pairs (here I'm "only" comparing n**2/2 pairs). The only way this could be sped up is if you know that the input groups are contiguous. In this case you only have to compare the successive pairs (O(n)). Let me know if this is the case and I'll update the answer.

See update for the alternative (supposing the groups are sorted).

A fun way to solve this is by using a Levenshtein_distancy if you know what the input should be.
from fuzzywuzzy import process
from Levenshtein import distance as levenshtein_distance

known_singers = ["Adele", "Beyonce", "Rihanna", "Taylor Swift", "Ed Sheeran"]
input_singers = ["Adel", "Beyoncé", "Brianna", "Tylor Swift", "Ed Sheeren", "Sting", "Madonna"]

def match_names(known_list, input_list):
matches = []
for name in input_list:
    match, score = process.extractOne(name, known_list)
    char_diff = levenshtein_distance(name, match)
    matches.append((name, match, score, char_diff))
return matches

results = match_names(known_singers, input_singers)

for input_name, matched_name, certainty, char_diff in results:
    print(f"Input: {input_name}, Matched: {matched_name}, Certainty: {certainty}%, Characters Off: {char_diff}")

Just make sure to identify the list you need, and use some form of error detection. For instance, if you should identify a cutoff point: Do you need 80% or 90% or even 99%?
Edit:
In case that we don't know the right list, we should use the existing list to cluster.
import Levenshtein as lev

def find_similar_artists_enhanced(artists, threshold=1):
    potential_errors = []

    for i in range(len(artists)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(artists)):
            artist1 = artists[i]
            artist2 = artists[j]
            distance = lev.distance(artist1, artist2)
            
            if distance <= threshold:
                potential_errors.append((artist1, artist2, distance))
    
    return potential_errors

artist_list = ["Beyoncé", "Beyonccé", "Adele", "Adelle", "Drake", "Drak", "Draco", "Eminem", "Eminen", "Rihanna", "Rihannas", "Rihannon"]

similar_artists = find_similar_artists_enhanced(artist_list, threshold=2)

print("Potential Spelling Errors:")
for artist1, artist2, distance in similar_artists:
    print(f"{artist1} -> {artist2} (Levenshtein Distance: {distance})")

This results in a list of items and their "neighbours"

unfortunately we can not have a predefined list of known_singers as I mentioned.

That makes it a lot more complicated. In that case, you could cluster based on majority vote, and use that as the known artists list. This could be done because spelling mistakes appear less often than usual. Lets say a cuttoff of less than 10% of the total list could lead to some good results. It's nowhere near bullet proof tough.

Yes it is , have look at my last comment on the question and tell me what you think about it, and especially how would you code it. It is essentially a unsupervised problem

there is no correct_list. where would you get correct_list?  If Bevonce is there 5 times and  Beyonce only once then Bevonce will have to be considered the correct one.

Can make something like this with scipy and Levenshtein distance
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform
from Levenshtein import distance as lev_dist

def correct_errors(
        arr: pd.Series,
        min_freq_of_real_name: int = 3, 
        max_lev_dist: int = 2
    ):
    dists = squareform(
        pdist(
            arr.values.reshape(-1, 1),
            lambda x, y: lev_dist(x[0], y[0])
        )  # slightly ugly because pdist compare vectors, not values
    ) 
    is_true_name = (dists == 0).sum(axis=1) > min_freq_of_real_name 
    # indexes of correct names (with repetitions)
    is_close = ((dists <= max_lev_dist).sum(axis=1) != 0) & ~is_true_name 
    # indexes of names which are not correct 
    # but have another name with lev_dist <= 2
    # (not garanteed to be close to true name, 
    # could be some two noise names close to each other)
    close2true = (
        dists[is_close][:, is_true_name] <= max_lev_dist
    ).max(axis=1)
    is_close[is_close] = close2true
    # (now garanteed to be close to true name)
    arr.loc[is_close] = arr[is_true_name].iloc[
        dists[is_close][:, is_true_name].argmin(axis=1)
    ].values
    # Change array inplace, make arr.copy() 
    # if you want to save original data
    return arr


Here is my code. It works on the data I gave in the question. let us know of any flaw that you may find.
from Levenshtein import distance
import pandas as pd
import io
import pprint as pp
from statistics import mode


def clustering(data):
    clusters = [
        [(id, obj)] for id, obj in data
    ]  # Initialize each object in its own cluster

    while True:
        merged = False
        for i in range(len(clusters)):
            for j in range(i + 1, len(clusters)):
                cluster1 = clusters[i]
                cluster2 = clusters[j]

                if cluster1[0][1] == cluster2[0][1]:  # Identical representatives
                    clusters[i] = cluster1 + cluster2
                    clusters.pop(j)
                    merged = True
                    break
                elif len(cluster1) >= 3 * len(cluster2) or len(cluster2) >= 3 * len(
                    cluster1
                ):
                    dist = distance(cluster1[0][1], cluster2[0][1])
                    if dist <= 2:
                        # Merge the larger cluster into the smaller one
                        if len(cluster1) > len(cluster2):
                            cluster1 += cluster2
                            clusters.pop(j)
                        else:
                            cluster2 += cluster1
                            clusters.pop(i)
                        merged = True
                        break

        if not merged:
            break

    return clusters


csvdata = """
Name,Year,Value
Bevonce,2008,296853
Beyonce,2007,1210744
Beyonce,2007,1222003
Beyonce,2007,1222003
Beyonce,2007,1222007
Beyoncel,2007,1222002
Nicki Mina,2015,2717068
Nicki Minaj,2015,2741567
Nicki Minaj,2015,2741567
Nicki Minaj,2015,2743565
Nicki Minajl,2015,2744974
Nicki Minal,2015,2741562
Nickl Minaj,2015,2741867
"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csvdata), sep=",")

print("Before:")
print(df)
df["id"] = df.index
data = df[["id", "Name"]].values.tolist()
result = clustering(data)
n_clusters = len(result)

for i in range(n_clusters):
    values_i = [value for key, value in result[i]]
    for k, v in result[i]:
        df.at[k, "Name"] = mode(values_i)

df = df[df.columns.drop("id")]
print("After:")
print(df)



import re
from statistics import mode
from rapidfuzz.distance import Levenshtein
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.neighbors import KDTree
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import umap


data = {
    'name': ['Bevonce', 'Beyonce', 'Beyonce', 'Beyonce', 'Beyonce', 'Beyoncel',
             'Nicki Mina', 'Nicki Minaj', 'Nicki Minaj', 'Nicki Minaj', 'Nicki Minajl',
             'Nicki Minal', 'Nickl Minaj'],
    'year': [2008, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015],
    'count': [296853, 1210744, 1222003, 1222003, 1222007, 1222002, 2717068, 2741567, 2741567,
              2743565, 2744974, 2741562, 2741867]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def preprocess_name(name):
    return re.sub(r'\W+', ' ', name).strip().lower()

df['clean_name'] = df['name'].apply(preprocess_name)

#Convert names to numerical features using TF-IDF
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
name_vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform(df['clean_name']).toarray()

#Apply UMAP to reduce dimensionality
# Adjust the number of components as needed
umap_model = umap.UMAP(n_components=2, n_neighbors=5) 
reduced_vectors = umap_model.fit_transform(name_vectors)

#Build the KDTree using reduced vectors
tree = KDTree(reduced_vectors)

#Find nearest neighbors and compute Levenshtein distance
threshold = 2
out = {}

for i, name in enumerate(df['clean_name']):
    k_neighbors = min(5, len(df) - 1)
    # Query 5 nearest neighbors using KDTree with reduced vectors
    # Use reduced_vectors[i] 
    dist, indices = tree.query([reduced_vectors[i]], k=k_neighbors)  
    
    # Filter based on Levenshtein distance
    close_indices = [idx for idx in indices[0] if 
                     Levenshtein.distance(df['clean_name'][i],df['clean_name'][idx]) <= threshold]
    
    if close_indices:
        cluster_names = df['name'].iloc[close_indices]
        common_name = mode(cluster_names)
        out.update({idx: common_name for idx in close_indices})

# Assign the common name to the DataFrame
df['common_name'] = df.index.map(out)

print(df)
'''
           name  year    count    clean_name  common_name
0        Bevonce  2008   296853       bevonce      Beyonce
1        Beyonce  2007  1210744       beyonce      Beyonce
2        Beyonce  2007  1222003       beyonce      Beyonce
3        Beyonce  2007  1222003       beyonce      Beyonce
4        Beyonce  2007  1222007       beyonce      Beyonce
5       Beyoncel  2007  1222002      beyoncel      Beyonce
6     Nicki Mina  2015  2717068    nicki mina  Nicki Minaj
7    Nicki Minaj  2015  2741567   nicki minaj  Nicki Minaj
8    Nicki Minaj  2015  2741567   nicki minaj  Nicki Minaj
9    Nicki Minaj  2015  2743565   nicki minaj  Nicki Minaj
10  Nicki Minajl  2015  2744974  nicki minajl  Nicki Minaj
11   Nicki Minal  2015  2741562   nicki minal  Nicki Minaj
12   Nickl Minaj  2015  2741867   nickl minaj  Nicki Minaj
'''

Best : Use annoy
import re
from statistics import mode
from rapidfuzz.distance import Levenshtein
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from annoy import AnnoyIndex  # For approximate nearest neighbors
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import umap


data = {
    'name': ['Bevonce', 'Beyonce', 'Beyonce', 'Beyonce', 'Beyonce', 'Beyoncel',
             'Nicki Mina', 'Nicki Minaj', 'Nicki Minaj', 'Nicki Minaj', 'Nicki Minajl',
             'Nicki Minal', 'Nickl Minaj'],
    'year': [2008, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015],
    'count': [296853, 1210744, 1222003, 1222003, 1222007, 1222002, 2717068, 2741567, 2741567,
              2743565, 2744974, 2741562, 2741867]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#Preprocess names
def preprocess_name(name):
    return re.sub(r'\W+', ' ', name).strip().lower()

df['clean_name'] = df['name'].apply(preprocess_name)

#Convert names to numerical features using TF-IDF
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
name_vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform(df['clean_name']).toarray()

# Apply UMAP to reduce dimensionality
umap_model = umap.UMAP(n_components=2, n_neighbors=5)
reduced_vectors = umap_model.fit_transform(name_vectors)

# Build the Annoy Index
# Number of trees (more trees give more accuracy but are slower)
n_trees = 10  
# Specify distance metric
annoy_index = AnnoyIndex(reduced_vectors.shape[1], 'euclidean')  

# Add vectors to Annoy index
for i, vec in enumerate(reduced_vectors):
    annoy_index.add_item(i, vec)

# Build the Annoy index with specified number of trees
annoy_index.build(n_trees)

# Find nearest neighbors and compute Levenshtein distance
threshold = 2
out = {}

for i, name in enumerate(df['clean_name']):
    # Query 5 nearest neighbors using Annoy
    indices = annoy_index.get_nns_by_vector(reduced_vectors[i], 5, include_distances=False)
    
    # Filter based on Levenshtein distance
    close_indices = [idx for idx in indices if 
                     Levenshtein.distance(df['clean_name'][i], df['clean_name'][idx]) <= threshold]
    
    if close_indices:
        cluster_names = df['name'].iloc[close_indices]
        common_name = mode(cluster_names)
        out.update({idx: common_name for idx in close_indices})

#Assign the common name to the DataFrame
df['common_name'] = df.index.map(out)

print(df)
'''
            name  year    count    clean_name  common_name
0        Bevonce  2008   296853       bevonce      Beyonce
1        Beyonce  2007  1210744       beyonce      Beyonce
2        Beyonce  2007  1222003       beyonce      Beyonce
3        Beyonce  2007  1222003       beyonce      Beyonce
4        Beyonce  2007  1222007       beyonce      Beyonce
5       Beyoncel  2007  1222002      beyoncel      Beyonce
6     Nicki Mina  2015  2717068    nicki mina  Nicki Minaj
7    Nicki Minaj  2015  2741567   nicki minaj  Nicki Minaj
8    Nicki Minaj  2015  2741567   nicki minaj  Nicki Minaj
9    Nicki Minaj  2015  2743565   nicki minaj  Nicki Minaj
10  Nicki Minajl  2015  2744974  nicki minajl  Nicki Minaj
11   Nicki Minal  2015  2741562   nicki minal  Nicki Minaj
12   Nickl Minaj  2015  2741867   nickl minaj  Nicki Minaj
'''

